# how to bind the data in gridview amount format 123,456.00?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a problem when binding the data in gridview. I am attempting to display the amount field in USA format like 123,456.00. How would I go about this with data binding?

The code I have so far is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>'>
       </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:boundcolumn datafield="Price" headertext="Tax" dataformatstring="{0:C}">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by dataformat string or you need any more help go through this link

[format data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790852/format-decimal-value-in-gridview)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="amount"  
     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="amount" DataFormatString="{0:n3}" />
```