# How would you format columns of a Gridview generated in code?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm pulling a list of businesses from my data where there has been some action with that business in a time frame, and for each business I'm listing the business and generating a gridview of the actions below it.  So I'm creating the gridview in code and writing the title and the corresponding data below for each business it on a web page.

This is all working fine.  What I want to do is apply formats to the data in those columns (by name or index).  I can't seem to find out how to do that programmatically.  Seems like you should be able to say "gridview.column(1).dataformatstring = "{0:c}" or something like that.  Has anyone done this?  Seems like it wouldn't be that unusual a task.

Code Sample (basic idea) from the loop:

```
        Dim DetailTable As DataTable = GetLastMonthsDetail(ProjectID)

        Dim gv As GridView = New GridView

        gv.DataSource = DetailTable
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        gv.DataBind()
```

Or if there is a way to copy a gridview definition to the created gridview, that would work, too.

I'm still looking for an answer, but for time's sake, I got rid of the gridview and just coded it to write out the HTML.

Comment: Are you creating entire GridView from code behind? Could you post a sample code what you have done so far?

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790852/format-decimal-value-in-gridview? Or post code how you are binding data to gridview.

Comment: It was easier to just forget the gridview and write out the html...  If anyone finds a solution to this, please let me know for future projects.